# Analyze fieldname in several tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have several tables which all have the column "Discovered" in common and the name always begin with "IT". The structure of each table is different, and I want to analyze just the date field "Discovered" in a Pivot query.

With this query I get all affected tables:

```
SELECT   MSysObjects.Name
FROM     MsysObjects
WHERE    Left$([Name],1)<>"~"
AND      Left$([Name],4)<>"Msys"
AND      MSysObjects.Type=1
AND MSysObjects.Name LIKE 'IT*'
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

But how do I get the field "Discovered" into this query?

Is it possible without using any VBA?

Comment: Off the top of my head I dont think youre going to be able to pull in the discovered column like this. I would actually use the result set to help you write a big union query which will then give you the results. However, you need to break it out by table, then you UNION query should have an additional column called "table" and then the name of the table as the value

Comment: ok than I will do the hugh UNION ALL query. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Glad I could help